# excel vba: insert formula with dynamic cell reference using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, formula

I am inserting the following hyperlink as a formula using vba:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""S:\Tasks\" & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\log.txt"",""View Log"")"
```

This works fine, however if my value in cell C was to change then my hyperlink becomes invalid and won't work because it has retained the value of the cell at the time in which the formula was entered.

I need a way of making a dynamic reference to my cell C in the event that the value should change then my link will also change.

Can someone please show me how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if I understood it right. Will `ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""S:\Tasks\"" & RC[-27] & ""\log.txt"",""View Log"")"` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking the value from column C and building a string using that value that looks like this:

`"S:\Tasks\FolderName\log.txt"`

Instead, what you want to do is build the following string:

`"S:\Tasks\" & C2 & "\log.txt"`

To do that, use this VBA code:

`ActiveSheet.Range("AD" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""S:\Tasks\"" & C" & ActiveCell.Row() & " & ""\log.txt"",""View Log"")"`